# Are there keylogger viruses that affect Ubuntu?

Tags: viruses

I just within the last few hours had my Amazon and Gmail accounts hijacked. Purchases were made through my Amazon account that I didn't authorize...in fact, I wasn't even in my room. According to Gmail, the IP address of when I got hijacked was where I live.

Enough rambling, here's my question: are there keylogger viruses on Ubuntu? I am not sure if either i accidentally let my password out there somewhere, or maybe I have a keylogger. I'm currently installing ClamAV to scan for viruses. Any help would be absolutely appreciated.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It could be couple of reasons. Did you used VPN or any shared network/wifi? Contact your internet sevice provider/VPN to confirm, state your date and time it happened. They will tracking back to you and and let you know what exactly had happened. From my experience by the way. Hope it help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there keylogger viruses that affect Ubuntu?

[Yes, there are](http://linux.slashdot.org/story/09/12/09/2215253/malware-found-hidden-in-screensaver-on-gnome-look), but the good news is that it is very hard to get infected, because of the way software installs (you need a root access). If you do not install some dodgy software, you are safe.

What most likely happened in your case, is someone ordered while you were away (and you didn't lock your computer).

Comment: The problem is I am the only one with access to my room. =/ According to the order, the hijacker was from a totally different state, but my IP was used...I know it's offtopic, but do you know why this could be?

Comment: @RyanMcClure I don't know how it is possible. See also [this question and answers](http://askubuntu.com/q/30032/6228). You can also ask this question on [security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be the result of a hack into other third party servers which have your password,credit card info etc.

It doesn't have to be a hack of your own machine.