# Is Ubuntu really more secure than Windows?

Tags: security

For years I am considering Ubuntu (or any Linux distribution) far secure than Windows. But when I read *[Most vulnerable operating systems and applications in 2014](http://www.gfi.com/blog/most-vulnerable-operating-systems-and-applications-in-2014/)* I couldn't believe it.

That's why I searched again, and I got a simlar explanation in *[Apple, Linux, not Windows, most vulnerable operating systems in 2014](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2887240/microsoft-subnet/apple-linux-not-windows-most-vulnerable-operating-systems-in-2014-ie-wins-worst-app.html)*

Now I am in confusion. Is Ubuntu really is secure than Windows?

Comment: Apart from the fact that the linked article seems obscure and lacks both foundation and details, this is not the place to start endless discussions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Ubuntu more secure than Windows or Mac OS X?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1069/why-is-ubuntu-more-secure-than-windows-or-mac-os-x)

Comment: Also see: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96004/are-there-technical-differences-which-make-linux-less-vulnerable-to-virus-than-w

Comment: All bugs in Linux are in the open. Does that chart also shows undisclosed bugs in Windows? Or bugs Microsoft found itself?

Comment: In case security purpose here have a look at this thread http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76492/security-in-windows-7-vs-ubuntu which would get some idea.

Comment: The "Windows is insecure" meme is really outdated, even in 2013 when this question was posted. It dates from when Windows wasn't designed to have any sort of security at all. Microsoft stepped up their security game a lot since then.

Comment: also, this doesn't talk about malware

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there are many different security and safety aspects. In some of them, Windows is more secure than Linux, while in others, less secure.

As for the past, Windows is well known for its hundreds or even thousands of security bugs in last 20 years. However, this is just the past. Microsoft since 2003 tries to improve security skills in their teams and make each new Windows edition more and more secure.

As for Ubuntu - it's a clone of Debian, which is generally secure by default. However there are a few key differences between Debian and Ubuntu: Ubuntu is configured in a different manner, to be more simple to learn and use for ordinary users, than Debian.

This enforces some security implications:

- Ubuntu has newer, less tested packages, with possible new, not yet spotted bugs (while Debian has at least 1-year old, "frozen" packages, with only security and other major bugs fixed)
- Ubuntu has PPA user-mode repositories - it's easier to accidentally install rogue software through PPA than through traditional Debian repositories
- Ubuntu has less strict package maintaining process - search for ownCloud maintainer problems, or Sun Java problems
- Ubuntu desktop install several custom movie-watching-related software, that is not covered by security team, furthermore, localized versions (at least Polish version) install even more such software
- Ubuntu sudo configuration allows possible rogue software to catch only the user's password to gain root privileges (no separate root password, like in classic Linux systems)

If you're looking for more secure alternative to Ubuntu, you should try Debian.

Comment: Seems a bit odd to mention ppa's (mostly launchpad, open source, code of conduct etc. etc.) as a risk, while in the windows environment people have to deal with a jungle of obscure, closed source applications when it comes to free and/or non-free additional applications.

Comment: Good point. However I mentioned PPA against Debian, not against Windows.

Comment: I understand, but the question is on Linux (Ubuntu) versus Windows :)

Comment: There are too many aspects to compare Linux vs Windows security, apart from historical problems. Updated and well configured Windows is generally secure, just like Ubuntu. The biggest current Windows problem is with users that work on accounts with administrative privileges, not with the system itself.

Comment: Just found this post, and the point about sudo password security bugs me. With sudo, the user's password can be spied on, while with su, it's the root password. Which one do you prefer ?